# Invoke a Jquery function from a webbrowser

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to get a data from a password protected webpage using webbrowser , which uses a div container with 3 JQuery data fields. The 2nd field depends on the 1st one, and the 3rd one of the 2nd one.I need to set those 3 comboboxes and hit submit in order to get the data I want to scrape. The problem is that once the 1st combobox changes, it invokes a function which populates the 2nd and 3rd boxes. I can't figure out how to invoke this function...

This is how the first combobox looks like:

Select s[DCOM1] Selection1

I managed to set the 1st combobox, however the big problem that I have is to invoke viewStep.onSChanged() , which supposed to populate the 2nd box, I just can't make it work.

The onSChanged function is located in a Jquery js. file

```
self.onsChanged = function(selectadj) {
    self.viewBasicsUpdated = true;
    log.debug('onsChanged');
    if (self.s) {
        self.adjEnabled = false;
        self.adj = null;
        self.auctionType = 'S';
        controller.ds.getadjList(self.s.id, function(response) {
            controller.applyUpdates(function() {
                self.adjList = response.data;
                // Add "Add adj" option (as first in array).
                self.adjList.unshift({
                    id : ADD_adj_ID,
                    fullName : controller.locale.getMessage('app.label.add.adj')
                });
                self.adjEnabled = true;
                self.standardEnabled = true;
                self.vixEnabled = (StringUtils.trimWS(self.s.vixFlag) === 'Y') ? true : false;
                self.offsiteEnabled = (StringUtils.trimWS(self.s.offsiteFlag) === 'Y') ? true : false;
                self.titOnlyEnabled = (StringUtils.trimWS(self.s.titOnlyFlag) === 'Y') ? true : false;
                self.salType = self.s.salType;

                self.titProcurementFlag = (StringUtils.trimWS(self.s.titProcurmentFlag) === 'Y') ? true : false;

                //Selects the adj when a new adj is added. 
                if(selectadj){
                    angular.forEach(self.adjList, function(object, index) {
                        log.debug("object.id++"+object.id);
                        if(object.id===self.newadjId){
                            self.adj=object;
                            log.debug("self.newadjId++"+object.id);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }else{
        controller.applyUpdates(function() {
            self.adj = null;
            self.adjEnabled = false;
            self.auctionType = 'S';
            self.standardEnabled = false;
            self.vixEnabled = false;
            self.offsiteEnabled = false;
            self.titOnlyEnabled = false;
            self.salType = null;
            self.titProcurementFlag = false;
        });`
    }
};
```

I have tried to invoke the function in many different options including invokescript, posting an identical post request as the one I see with Fiddler (I guess it fails since the cookie is different) but everything fails. Is there a way to execute this function?

Comment: I have read and reread your question many times but i can't understand what the problem is nor what your question is. Could you rewrite it for clarity so we can give better help?

Comment: I am basically trying to set the the right selection in a panel with 3 dynamically populated comboboxes, that leads to the data I need to scrap,  I managed to set the first combobox to the option I need, however I can't invoke the function that populate the 2nd and 3rd boxes, based on the selection of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

When setting values on input controls with Javascript the DOM events might not fire, depending on how the values are set.

Instead of trying to execute the very same function that the webpage would normally trigger, in this case `self.onsChanged`, fire the event on the control that you updated.

```
$("#selectBox1").val("Value A");
$("#selectBox1").change();
```

https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by using HTTPWebRequest, Logging in to the website, and posting an Ajax call. Thank you all for your help :)